# Цикл подобный For на PHP для smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Прошу помощи специалистов и просто хороших людей. Не могли бы вы подсказать мне, как реализовать подобное

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

На Smarty. Вот именно, чтобы была возможность выставлять количество повторов и способы увеличения или уменьшения. И возможность задавать начало отсчета. Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: Документацию, видимо, читать не пробовал..  Или не умеешь..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[{section},{sectionelse}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.function.section.tpl)

```
{section name=foo start=10 loop=20 step=2}
    {$smarty.section.foo.index}
{/section}
<hr />
{section name=bar loop=21 max=6 step=-2}
    {$smarty.section.bar.index}
{/section}
```

типо того :-) да?

Comment: Во! Дружище, спасибо тебе огромное) Выручил)

Comment: и чем вам этот смарти так удобен?

Comment: @mountpoint всем. Начиная от того, что он встраивается в html код и заканчивая тем, что мной написан компилятор под js.

Comment: @lampa, ну это дело вкуса. Сколько уже работаю в вебе, не перевариваю смарти

Comment: @mountpoint и какой предпочитаешь?

Comment: @lampa, предпочитаю хардкор: смесь пыха и хтмл

Comment: @mountpoint ну кому как)) Я тоже раньше не особо заморачивался и прямо в шаблон встраивал. А потом попробовал на проекте одном, и понравилось, удобнее намного, сразу видно отделение шаблона от кода. Плюс плюшки в виде кеширования берут своё.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width=100%>
<tr>
{foreach name=inner key=key item=item from=$customer}

<td>{$key|capitalize}</td>

{/foreach}

<tr></table>
```

Comment: И что? Это по Вашему подходит под то, что я просил? Если да, то не могли бы Вы еще несколько секунд уделить, рассказав мне, каким образом задавать начало и конец выполнения цикла?